# Adding shadow to UIView on top of UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have a VC that has a `UITableView` all over the screen, except the first 66px from the top. There, I have a custom `UIView` I call "Toolbar" which contains a title and a button.

It looks like this:

[image: Image 1]

I'm trying to add a shadow to the "Toolbar" that will be visible on top of the `UITableView`. I'm adding it like this:

[image: Image 2]

For some reason, I don't see any shadow when I run the app.

What am I doing wrong? Does anybody know?

Thank you!

Comment: are you setting cliptobounds?

Comment: @kthorat `clipToBounds` is set to `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shadow needs some spaces to be shown, you have to add some vertical spaces between your top view(toolbar) and the Table view.

for having a result like the following:
[image]

you need to add some space:
[image]

ans I also use the following code for adding the shadow:

```
toolbar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
toolbar.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
toolbar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
toolbar.layer.shadowRadius = 10
toolbar.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

Comment: Why can't the shadow be shown on the tableView itself?

Comment: because shadow itself has a height, so it needs an empty space.

Comment: So how can I achieve a shadow from the toolbar on top of the tableView when the tableView is snaped to the toolbar? I've already seen that in other apps

Comment: At the end it will be shown in a way like it is added on top of the tableview, try it.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more what should I do practically? Just to update the constant of the top constraint of the tableView to, for example, 10?